# HTML Agility Pack using XPATH questions

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using this code to get all tables in my html document:

```
var tables = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table[@class='something']");
```

Inside each table i have multiple rows and multiples columns. I have something like this so far:

```
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes(".//TR");
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
{
    HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//TD");

    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; ++j)
    {
        string value = cols[j].InnerText;
    }
}
```

I need help to understand the use of XPATH, since i can't find online documentation. For example how i would get the content if my html document is like this:

```
<table class="something">
  <colgroup>...</colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I only want what the content of "td"

Comment: "Please help me find examples" is off-topic on SO. (If I misunderstood your question consider editing it to make it clear what you are looking for/expect). This search can get you started - http://www.bing.com/search?q=xpath+samples . If you like details - see [XPath  specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). You'll usually find XPath samples applied to searches in XML - they apply directly to your case as it is essentially what what HtmlAgilityPack does - converts "free form HTML" into XML tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath query to get `td` tags located inside a `table` with class "something" is

```
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//table[@class=""something""]//td");
```

This means:

- `//` selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are
- `//table[@class="something"]` selects `table` tags with the attribute `class` equals to 'something' anywhere in the document.
- `//table[@class="something"]//td` selects `td` tags that have as a parent, a grand parent or a grand grant parent a `table` tag

Comment: so if use //table//tbody//td it gets all td tags inside tbody?

Comment: With the specified HTML, yes. You can also use `//table/tbody//td` because `tbody` is the direct descendant of `table`. Note that in `thead` you should use `th` instead of `td`. If you do so, the suggested XPath query will work without specifying `tbody`